# PM2 Process monitoring and send Alert as email (Gmail smtp)

Tags: node.js, email, smtp

I need to Monitor my pm2 process.If any process goes "errored" state or "stoped" state, i need to send alert email to specific persons.
I configure setting as this.

1. Install pm2 heath usng `pm2 install pm2-health` command.
2. Then open */root/.pm2/module_conf.json* and provide below details.

```json
{
    "pm2-health": {
        "smtp": {
            "host": "smtp.gmail.com",
            "port": 587,
            "user": "test.324321@gmail.com",
            "password": "uhjyetucsscs",
            "disabled": false
        },
        "mailTo": "xxxx@gmail.com",
        "replyTo": "",
        "batchPeriodM": 0,
        "batchMaxMessages": 0,
        "events": [
            "exit"
        ],
        "exceptions": true,
        "messages": true,
        "messageExcludeExps": [],
        "metric": {},
        "metricIntervalS": 60,
        "aliveTimeoutS": 300,
        "addLogs": true,
        "appsExcluded": [],
        "snapshot": {
            "url": "",
            "token": "",
            "auth": {
                "user": "",
                "password": ""
            },
            "disabled": false
        }
    },
    "module-db-v2": {
        "pm2-health": {}
    }
}
```

In Smtp code block i created new gmail account and provide new gmail address as user.
Then enable 2fa authuntication and generate "app-password", then copy that auto-generated value and paste under "password" feild.

Then I test this settup by shutting down my test pm2 process. and i can see these log under "pm2 heath process". also alert email is not received.

> 1|pm2-heal | 2023-07-04T09:48:30.353Z: can't send mail -> getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN your-smtp-host

this settup in my local machine and internet connectivity is there.